# Index out of bound Exception while reading Holding Register using jamod library

Tags: java, exception

i have implemented a TCP Modbus Master using the jamod library 
The code requests for holding registers from the Modbus and reads the response and write it in a file. also it calculates the transaction time 
Here is my code :

```
public class TCPModbus_Task {
    private static ModbusTCPMaster tcp_Modbusmaster;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int NoOfRequests = 0;// loop variable
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
        int ref = 0; //the reference; offset where to start reading from i.e. the start address.
        int count = 0; //the number of DI's to read
        int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction
        String addr = null;
        long Avg_diff = 0;
        int reg_val = 0;
        Register[] registers = new Register[200];
        BufferedWriter output = null;
        long Avg_Time = 0;
        try {
            //Setup Parameters
            if(args.length < 3)
                System.exit(1);
            else {
                try {
                    String astr = args[0];
                    int idx = astr.indexOf(':');
                    if(idx != -1) {
                        port = Integer.parseInt(astr.substring(idx+1));
                        addr = astr.substring(0, idx);
                    }
                    ref = Integer.decode(args[1]).intValue();
                    count = Integer.decode(args[2]).intValue();
                    if (args.length == 4) {
                      repeat = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
                    }  

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            //ModbusTCPMaster instance ( constructor called )
            tcp_Modbusmaster = new ModbusTCPMaster(addr, port);

            //Connect to slave
            tcp_Modbusmaster.connect();

            //Create file write modbus data
            File file = new File("D:/MODbusData.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                     file.createNewFile();
            }


            do {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    //TimeStamp before request
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5.30"));
                    long time1 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                    String Time1 = String.valueOf(time1);
                    System.out.println("Time1 = " + time1);         


                    //Read Modbus register (function code = 3)
                    registers = tcp_Modbusmaster.readMultipleRegisters(ref, count, 255);

                    System.out.println("Number of Modbus registers : " + registers.length);
                    System.out.println("\nModbus register values : \n");
                    for (int i=0; i<registers.length; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(registers[i].getValue());
                    }

                    //TimeStamp After response
                    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5.30"));
                    long time2 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
                    String Time2 = String.valueOf(time2);

                    System.out.println("Time2 = " + time2);
                    int diff = (int)(time2-time1);
                    String Transac_time = String.valueOf(diff);
                    System.out.println("Transacion(time2 - time1) time in ms=" + diff);
                    NoOfRequests++;
                    Avg_diff = Avg_diff + (long)diff;

                    //Writing Modbus data and transaction timing to file
                    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));

                    output.write("Time1 in ms:  " + Time1 + "\n\r");
                    output.write("Modbus data: \n");
                    for(int i=0;i<registers.length;i++)
                    {
                        reg_val = registers[i].getValue();
                        String Register_value = String.valueOf(reg_val);                                                                        
                        output.write(Register_value + " ");
                    }
                    output.write("\n" + "Time2 in ms:  " + Time2 + "\n\r");
                    output.write("Transaction time in ms:  " + Transac_time + "\n");

                    //Calculating the Average Transaction Time
                    if(NoOfRequests>=repeat)
                    {
                        Avg_Time = Avg_diff/NoOfRequests;
                        String AVG_Time = String.valueOf(Avg_Time);
                        output.write("Avg Transaction time in ms:  " + AVG_Time + "\n\r");                          
                    }

                    output.close();

            }while(NoOfRequests < repeat);

            tcp_Modbusmaster.disconnect();



        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But if i give the count value (i.e number of word(register) to read from slave) greater than 123, i want to read 200 holding register from the Modbus slave(having the Modbus map). i am able read upto count = 123 register in one request without exception.

it give the following exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:195)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:192)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusTCPMaster.java:282)
    at com.axonet.modbus.TCPModbus_Task.main(TCPModbus_Task.java:79)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.BytesInputStream.readUnsignedByte(BytesInputStream.java:169)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:200)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:192)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusTCPMaster.java:282)
    at com.axonet.modbus.TCPModbus_Task.main(TCPModbus_Task.java:79)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.BytesInputStream.readUnsignedByte(BytesInputStream.java:169)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:200)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:192)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusTCPMaster.java:282)
    at com.axonet.modbus.TCPModbus_Task.main(TCPModbus_Task.java:79)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.BytesInputStream.readUnsignedByte(BytesInputStream.java:169)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:200)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:192)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusTCPMaster.java:282)
    at com.axonet.modbus.TCPModbus_Task.main(TCPModbus_Task.java:79)
net.aeplmm.modbus.ModbusIOException: Executing transaction failed (tried 3 times)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:197)
    at net.aeplmm.modbus.facade.ModbusTCPMaster.readMultipleRegisters(ModbusTCPMaster.java:282)
    at com.axonet.modbus.TCPModbus_Task.main(TCPModbus_Task.java:79)
```

It would be helpful if anybody have any suggestions.

Comment: I have used the ModbusTCPMaster class to implement the TCP modbus master.

Comment: What if you read it twice? First 100 register and after that registers from 100-200.

Comment: Smells like a bug in `Modbus`, it shouldn't allow a low-level `IndexOutOfBoundException` to reach the caller. That still doesn't imply your code isn't at fault, just that the library should give a more meaningful error message.

Comment: @jure: That is a solution but actually i need to complete a single transaction in  10ms. right now it is taking around 10 ms. if i read twice, the transaction time will increase

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: By Modbus. you mean the jamod library. right?  are you implying that there is some error in the code??

Comment: Then you could try https://github.com/steveohara/j2mod which goal is to" This is a project to bring the j2mod library up to date.". So it's quite similar to jamod.

Comment: I mean the `net.aeplmm.modbus.io` package, whatever that is.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Actually i traced down the code in the library where the exception is coming from.it is giving "IndexOutOfBoundsException" exception in the "java.io.DataInputStream.read" method where it is called in the library but the library level code implementation inside is not making any sense to me.

Comment: @jure: Thanks for the suggestion i will take a look at it.

Comment: The stack trace indicates an error from `BufferedInputStream.read`, which is called from `DataInputStream.read`. The line of code that does it is `if ((off | len | (off + len) | (b.length - (off + len))) < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();`